# Landscape and portrait mode in tablet Android

Tags: android, rotation, tablet

I have a question.I wanna use the app in landscape and portrait mode but I need information about when I rotate the device portrait to landscape, the app split to 2 fragments.

I research many websites but I haven't necessary infos about that. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

```
 productFlavors {
        phone {
            applicationId "packageName.app.phone"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IsPhone', 'true'
            versionName ""
        }
        tablet {
            applicationId "packageName.app.tablet"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IsPhone', 'false'
            versionName ""
        }
    }
```

I split my apk.I have a phone.apk and tablet.apk.

Comment: you can specify landscape mode in layout_land folder.

Comment: Yes I know about that but I split my apk with gradle.I have a phone.apk and a  tablet.apk.When I create a "layout_land " folder, haven't worked for me.

Comment: You should see this documentation http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html about Supporting Tablets and Handsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to know when the device rotate you can try something like this.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // "landscape"
    } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //"portrait"
    }
}
```

But usually you are not supposed to do this. You just need to provide one layout for `portrait` and another one  for `lanscape` and then let the layout load the required Fragments.

In the case of to separate phone.apk and a tablet.apk each apk should be shipped, using gradle, with its respective set of layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could check angle of it and do anything.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidOrientationSensor extends Activity {

    OrientationEventListener myOrientationEventListener;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        myOrientationEventListener
                = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("GORIO", "angle: " + String.valueOf(arg0));
            }
        };

        if (myOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myOrientationEventListener.enable();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        myOrientationEventListener.disable();
    }
}
```